# Face detection and give filter

Tags: matlab, face-detection

```
FDetect = vision.CascadeObjectDetector;

%// Read the input image

I = imread('face.jpg');

%// Returns Bounding Box values based on number of objects
BB = step(FDetect,I);

figure,
imshow(I); 
hold on
for i = 1:size(BB,1)
   rectangle('Position',BB(i,:),'LineWidth',2.5,'LineStyle','','EdgeColor','r');
end
title('Face Detection');
hold off;
```

filter:

```
E = imerode(I,strel('square',5));

figure, imshow(E);
```

My problem is how to give filters only IN rectangle face area.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to extract just region of your image that is within the bounding box, and then apply your `imerode` operation on just that part.

The Bounding Box is of the form [x,y,width,height]. We will need to convert this to pixels.

```
%// Ensure that we are working with integers.
BB(k,:) = round(BB(k,:));

%// Sample all rows and columns within this bounding box
rows = BB(k,2):sum(BB(k,[2 4]))
cols = BB(k,1):sum(BB(k,[1 3]))

%// Apply the imerode operation on just these pixels
I(rows,cols) = imerode(I(rows,cols), strel('square', 5));
```